# Android ViewPager onClickListener reacts even if other fragment is show

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I have a ViewPager which holds two fragments. one `fragment` contains nothing and the other `fragment` contains a `gridview` with `ImageViews`. 
The `ImageViews` have a `onClickListener` set.
Everything works fine so far... but when i am on the fragment which contains nothing and tap somewhere the onClickListener of the other fragments gridviews imagview reacts to my click even if its elements aren't visible.

I could change my `onClickListener` so that it checks which fragment is shown but is that really the way i should do it ??? it feels a bit dirty

This is my FragmentStatePageAdapter

```
public class OwnPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

private BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage();
private Apps apps = new Apps();
private Home_Screen ac;

public OwnPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Home_Screen activity) {
    super(fm);
    this.ac = activity;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position == 0) {
    return backgroundImage;
    }else if(position == 1) {

        return  this.apps;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
}
```

This is my BaseAdapter

```
public class AppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private AppLauncher launcherListener = new AppLauncher();
private ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> appList;
private Context ctx;
public AppAdapter(ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> listOfApps, Context ctx){
    this.appList = listOfApps;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.appList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    ImageView v = new ImageView(this.ctx);
    v.setImageDrawable(this.appList.get(i).loadIcon(this.ctx.getPackageManager()));
    return v;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if(view != null){
        ((ImageView) view).setImageDrawable(this.appList.get(i).loadIcon(this.ctx.getPackageManager()));
        view.setTag(i);

        return view;
    }

    ImageView v = new ImageView(this.ctx);

    v.setImageDrawable(this.appList.get(i).loadIcon(this.ctx.getPackageManager()));
    v.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    v.setOnClickListener(launcherListener);
    v.setTag(i);
    return v;

}



private class AppLauncher implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        ctx.startActivity(ctx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appList.get((int) view.getTag()).packageName));
    }
}
}
```

Thats my fragment class

```
public class Apps extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>>{


private GridView gridview;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this).forceLoad();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_apps, container, false);
    this.gridview = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.apptable);

    return rootView;


}

@Override
public Loader<ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new AppLoader(getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>> loader, ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> data) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Done with loading Apps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    this.gridview.setAdapter(new AppAdapter(data,getActivity()));
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>> loader) {

}
}
```

Comment: just set clickable=true on root layout of the first fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While i cant find any specific cause to your problem i have to suggest a cleaner way of achieving the same result you're seeking, using an inner class just to capture click events is dirty and just unnecessary. it is quite possible that using this method will solve your problem as well.

Instead of using AppLauncher class which implements an OnClickListener and then set it manualy for each item, why not using an OnItemClickListener on the whole gridview ? it will take care of click events for each item and is specific only to items inside your gridview so you dont have to worry about any leaks like you would using inner classes.

In your fragment implement OnItemClickListener :

```
public class Apps extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>>, OnItemClickListener
```

Then in your fragment's onCreate simply set the adapter to the gridview:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and implement the necessary method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    getActivity().startActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appList.get(position).packageName));
}
```

Now you can remove the OnClickListener logic from your gridview's adapter and it should work fine, my guess is it will also solve your problem, and even if not, hey at least you end up with a cleaner code.

Another thing i find odd about your code is that you override getItemId() yet always return 0, make sure this is the normal behaviour you're looking for since im not sure it is.

Good luck.

Comment: I put the code of the fragment into the original question

Comment: Yea thnx it works when i use onItemClicked Listener instead of onClickListener